# Remote Glassfish 3.2.1 server suddenly stops showing log in Netbeans 7

Tags: logging, glassfish-3, netbeans-7

Oh please!!

I have been working with a remote Glassfish 3 with Netbeans 7 for a week.
Suddenly my Glassfish server stopped logging... The logs don't show up anywhere... not in Netbeans not anywhere else!

I friggin uninstalled the server and reinstalled it, but again the same old same old!

Could someone please help me out here...

Comment: Maybe your application is using some kind of Log library to redirect the output to a file, database or similar. Have you tried `System.out.println` to see if it redirects output to the console?

Comment: No I didn't... lets see .

Comment: So, I just printed out a statement inside my Servlet and I found out that it is only printing out in terminal... My server is running remotely on a linux machine. I start my GF server by logging into my server through SSH and start the server... in this terminal window I am seeing my system.out.println... i don't know what it means and how to solve it

Comment: I have found that in my configuration 
**was** showing those values 

    com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole <true>
    com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging <true>

but according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/set-log-attributes.htm 
they should be set to 

    asadmin set-log-attributes com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=false 
    asadmin set-log-attributes com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your logger is being redirected somewhere else but the standard `server.log` file. You can try to deploy a different application and see if it is able to log into `server.log`.

If it does then your should check your original application for [Apache Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) or [similar libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/logging) configuration files, they may be redirecting your output somewhere else (such as a a file or database).

If it does not then the problem may be your [Application Server Logging configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#scrolltoc). Check if the Log is being redirected to `server.log`, if the log levels are set adequately and if some custom `logging.properties` file or `Log Handler` are not killing the log output or redirecting it somewhere else.